# Why is add_custom_target always considered out of date?

Tags: cmake

According to [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html), `add_custom_target()` creates a target that "ALWAYS CONSIDERED OUT OF DATE". However, the documentation [also says](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) that `add_dependencies()` can add dependencies between top-level targets, including one added by `add_custom_target()`. If `add_custom_target()` is always executed, is there any practical purpose to using it with `add_dependencies()`?

Answer (score 5):

As far as CMake is concerned, [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_custom_target.html) does not produce anything that it could track to determine whether the target is out-of-date.

Contrast that with [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_custom_command.html), where you have the ability to specify an `OUTPUT` produced by the command. As far as CMake knows, a custom target is just a black box, where anything could happen. That's what makes them so difficult to integrate correctly into a build.

Note that by default, custom targets are skipped altogether, you can only build them explicitly (eg. by calling `make <my_target_name>`). You can make them part of the default build target by either specifying the `ALL` option when calling `add_custom_target` or make another target, which is already part of the default build target, depend on your custom target.

You usually cannot add this dependency by depending on one of its output artifacts, since, as far as CMake is concerned, the custom target does not produce anything. That's why you have to use the more archaic `add_dependencies` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> If `add_custom_target()` is always executed, is there any practical purpose to using it with `add_dependencies()`?

1. Without *ALL* option `add_custom_target()` isn't built automatically.
2. Call `add_dependencies(A B)` makes sure that a target `B` will be built **before** a target `A`, so a target `A` may safetly use files, created for target `B`.

Answer (score 1):

CMake [article](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/add_custom_target.html) about `add_custom_target()` command is not very clear, so a similar question arose for me as well. We have two aspects of adding a custom target to a buildsystem:

1. is this target needed to be used in our buildsystem? "Used" in a sense of "materialized" - when a custom target is not only added to a buildsystem definition, but also corresponding logic is added to the generated buildsystem, so this logic will be executed during build.
2. when this target should be (re)built (assuming we have already decided that this custom target must be used in our buildsystem)?

Considering the first question, if we want a custom target to be used in our buildsystem we should use either "All" option or `add_dependencies()` command. I think that the phrase from docs:

> By default nothing depends on the custom target.

implies that if we do not use "All" option or make any other target dependent on a custom target - this custom target logic will not appear in the generated buildsystem.

Regarding the second aspect, the phrase:

> Add a target with no output so it will always be built.

says that a custom target is always being built when we (re)build our project (taking into account we have already made use of it using "All"/add_dependencies()), because since custom targets produce no output that  build dependency resolution logic can track, it is impossible to determine when such target should be rebuilt (so it is assumed that a custom target should always be built).

**Summarizing the written above:** we should use a custom target with `add_dependencies()` command when this target is needed not only to be defined in a buildsystem, but also used in the generated buildsystem, because a custom target is always executed only if it has been already materialized in the generated buildsystem.